# how to write two keys and one value in the map output?

Tags: java, hadoop

i want to put the file format (jpg) as the second key ???

```
public static class Img2GrayMapper extends Mapper<NullWritable, BufferedImageWritable, Text,BytesWritable> {


        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 

        @Override

        protected void map(NullWritable key, BufferedImageWritable value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {


            BufferedImage colorImage = value.getImage();

            ImageIO.write(colorImage, "jpg", bos );
            byte [] data = bos.toByteArray();
            BytesWritable b = new BytesWritable(data);
            Text a = new Text(value.getFileName());
            context.write(a, b);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to give a bit more context here, Mapper from hadoop?

Comment: how please @lssilva